# Sort slicers data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

how can I sort data in slicers as shown in this photo

[image: Slicer image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please tell us how did you get the number in these slicers?

Answer (score 0):

Format your data to be

```
01 Sat
02 Sun
...
etc
```

EDIT:
You can quickly make 365 entries using the SEQUENCE function inside the DATE function. Here are two options:

[image]

You can adjust the display text by changing the string at the end.

```
=TEXT(DATE(2022,1,SEQUENCE(365)), "dd ddd")
=TEXT(DATE(2022,1,SEQUENCE(365)), "dd mmm - ddd")
```

Comment: Those are times of the month, where they change from month to month and now I have to make 365 entries. any faster solution?

Comment: Pls see my edit.